# Illustrator "specify" JavaScript tweak

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

I've just started out in the world of design and recently discovered scripts in Illustrator CS6. I currently use a script called "specify" in Illustrator(jsx). I've included a description of what this code actually does.

"Select one object and run the script, Confirm the orientation of the measurement. This will specify the width or height of the object. Select two objects and run the script. This will specify the horizontal or vertical gap between the two objects. If you group several objects and run the script, you will get the size of the group of objects."

I love this script however I wish I knew about coding and scripting as I would like to tweak this script so instead of saying "20" I would like it to include "mm" after the width/height. I was hoping that someone on here could help me out with this. I hope it is possible to do this, I've included the code below.

Thanks in advance.

Download link - http://cdn.tutsplus.com/vector/uploads/legacy/articles/2010/article_illustrator_plugin_scripts/scripts/specify.zip

I tried posting the code but didn't have much luck.

```
    /*
* Description: An Adobe Illustrator script that automates measurements of objects. This is an early version that has not been sufficiently tested. Use at your own risks.
* Usage: Select 1 to 2 page items in Adobe Illustrator, then run this script by selecting File > Script > Other Scripts > (choose file)
* License: GNU General Public License Version 3. (http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0-standalone.html)
*
* Copyright (c) 2009. William Ngan.
* http://www.metaphorical.net
*/

// Create an empty dialog window near the upper left of the screen 
var dlg = new Window('dialog', 'Spec');
dlg.frameLocation = [100,100];
dlg.size = [250,250];

dlg.intro = dlg.add('statictext', [20,20,150,40] );
dlg.intro.text = 'First select 1 or 2 items';

dlg.where = dlg.add('dropdownlist', [20,40,150,60] );
dlg.where.selection = dlg.where.add('item', 'top');
dlg.where.add('item', 'bottom');
dlg.where.add('item', 'left');
dlg.where.add('item', 'right');

dlg.btn = dlg.add('button', [20,70,150,90], 'Specify', 'spec');



// document
var doc = activeDocument;

// spec layer
try {
    var speclayer =doc.layers['spec'];
} catch(err) {
    var speclayer = doc.layers.add();
    speclayer.name = 'spec';
}

// measurement line color
var color = new RGBColor;
color.green = 255;
color.blue = 0;

// gap between measurement lines and object
var gap = 2;

// size of measurement lines.
var size = 10;

// number of decimal places
var decimals = 0;

// pixels per inch
var dpi = 72;

/**
    Start the spec
*/
function startSpec() {

    if (doc.selection.length==1) {
        specSingle( doc.selection[0].geometricBounds, dlg.where.selection.text );
    } else if (doc.selection.length==2) {
        specDouble( doc.selection[0], doc.selection[1], dlg.where.selection.text );
    } else {
            alert('please select 1 or 2 items');
    }

    dlg.close ();
}




/**
    Spec the gap between 2 elements
*/
function specDouble( item1, item2, where ) {

    var bound = new Array(0,0,0,0);

    var a =  item1.geometricBounds;
    var b =  item2.geometricBounds;

    if (where=='top' || where=='bottom') {

        if (b[0]>a[0]) { // item 2 on right,

            if (b[0]>a[2]) { // no overlap
                bound[0] =a[2];
                bound[2] = b[0];
            } else { // overlap
                bound[0] =b[0];
                bound[2] = a[2];
            }
        } else if (a[0]>=b[0]){ // item 1 on right

            if (a[0]>b[2]) { // no overlap
                bound[0] =b[2];
                bound[2] = a[0];
            } else { // overlap
                bound[0] =a[0];
                bound[2] = b[2];
            }
        }

        bound[1] = Math.max (a[1], b[1]);
        bound[3] = Math.min (a[3], b[3]);

    } else {

        if (b[3]>a[3]) { // item 2 on top
            if (b[3]>a[1]) { // no overlap
                bound[3] =a[1];
                bound[1] = b[3];
            } else { // overlap
                bound[3] =b[3];
                bound[1] = a[1];
            }
        } else if (a[3]>=b[3]){ // item 1 on top

            if (a[3]>b[1]) { // no overlap
                bound[3] =b[1];
                bound[1] = a[3];
            } else { // overlap
                bound[3] =a[3];
                bound[1] = b[1];
            }
        }

        bound[0] = Math.min(a[0], b[0]);
        bound[2] = Math.max (a[2], b[2]);
    }
    specSingle(bound, where );
}


/**
    spec a single object
    @param bound item.geometricBound
    @param where 'top', 'bottom', 'left,' 'right'
*/
function specSingle( bound, where ) {


    // width and height
    var w = bound[2]-bound[0];
    var h = bound[1]-bound[3];

    // a & b are the horizontal or vertical positions that change
    // c is the horizontal or vertical position that doesn't change
    var a = bound[0];
    var b = bound[2];
    var c = bound[1];

    // xy='x' (horizontal measurement), xy='y' (vertical measurement)
    var xy = 'x';

    // a direction flag for placing the measurement lines.
    var dir = 1;

    switch( where ) {

        case 'top':
            a = bound[0];
            b = bound[2];
            c = bound[1];
            xy = 'x';
            dir = 1;
            break;

        case 'bottom':
            a = bound[0];
            b = bound[2];
            c = bound[3];
            xy = 'x';
            dir = -1;
            break;

        case 'left':
            a = bound[1];
            b = bound[3];
            c = bound[0];
            xy = 'y';
            dir = -1;
            break;

        case 'right':
            a = bound[1];
            b = bound[3];
            c = bound[2];
            xy = 'y';
            dir = 1;
            break;

    }

    // create the measurement lines
    var lines = new Array(); 

    // horizontal measurement
    if (xy=='x') {

        // 2 vertical lines
        lines[0]= new Array( new Array(a, c+(gap)*dir) );
        lines[0].push ( new Array(a, c+(gap+size)*dir) );
        lines[1]= new Array( new Array(b, c+(gap)*dir) );
        lines[1].push( new Array(b, c+(gap+size)*dir) );

        // 1 horizontal line
        lines[2]= new Array( new Array(a, c+(gap+size/2)*dir ) );
        lines[2].push( new Array(b, c+(gap+size/2)*dir ) );

        // create text label
        if (where=='top') {
            var t = specLabel( w, (a+b)/2, lines[0][1][1] );
            t.top += t.height;
        } else {
            var t = specLabel( w, (a+b)/2, lines[0][0][1] );
            t.top -= t.height;
        }
        t.left -= t.width/2;

    // vertical measurement
    } else {

        // 2 horizontal lines
        lines[0]= new Array( new Array( c+(gap)*dir, a) );
        lines[0].push ( new Array( c+(gap+size)*dir, a) );
        lines[1]= new Array( new Array( c+(gap)*dir, b) );
        lines[1].push( new Array( c+(gap+size)*dir, b) );

        //1 vertical line
        lines[2]= new Array( new Array(c+(gap+size/2)*dir, a) );
        lines[2].push( new Array(c+(gap+size/2)*dir, b) );

        // create text label
        if (where=='left') {
            var t = specLabel( h, lines[0][1][0], (a+b)/2 );
            t.left -= t.width;
        } else {
            var t = specLabel( h, lines[0][0][0], (a+b)/2 );
            t.left += size;
        }
        t.top += t.height/2;
    }

    // draw the lines
    var specgroup = new Array(t);

    for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
        var p = doc.pathItems.add();
        p.setEntirePath ( lines[i] );
        setLineStyle( p, color );
        specgroup.push( p );
    }

    group(speclayer, specgroup );

}


/**
    Create a text label that specify the dimension
*/
function specLabel( val, x, y) {

        var t = doc.textFrames.add();
        t.textRange.characterAttributes.size = 8;
        t.textRange.characterAttributes.alignment = StyleRunAlignmentType.center;

        var v = val;
        switch (doc.rulerUnits) {
            case RulerUnits.Inches: 
                v = val/dpi;
                v = v.toFixed (decimals);
                break;

            case RulerUnits.Centimeters:
                v = val/(dpi/2.54);
                v = v.toFixed (decimals);
                break;

            case RulerUnits.Millimeters:
                v = val/(dpi/25.4);
                v = v.toFixed (decimals);
                break;

            case RulerUnits.Picas:
                v = val/(dpi/6);
                var vd = v - Math.floor (v);
                vd = 12*vd;
                v =  Math.floor(v)+'p'+vd.toFixed (decimals);
                break;

            default:
                v = v.toFixed (decimals);
        }

        t.contents = v;
        t.top = y;
        t.left = x;

        return t;

}

function setLineStyle(path, color) {
        path.filled = false;
        path.stroked = true;
        path.strokeColor = color;
        path.strokeWidth = 0.5;

        return path;
}


/**
* Group items in a layer
*/
function group( layer, items, isDuplicate) {

    // create new group
    var gg = layer.groupItems.add();

    // add to group
    // reverse count, because items length is reduced as items are moved to new group
    for(var i=items.length-1; i>=0; i--) {

        if (items[i]!=gg) { // don't group the group itself
            if (isDuplicate) {
                newItem = items[i].duplicate (gg, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING);
            } else {
                items[i].move( gg, ElementPlacement.PLACEATBEGINNING );
            }
        }
    }

    return gg;
}




// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

dlg.btn.addEventListener ('click', startSpec );
dlg.show();
```

Comment: `.zip` to download? You do realize people will do not waste their time on that?

Comment: OT: in the script top comment it says `This is an early version that has not been sufficiently tested. Use at your own risks.`.. are there newer versions?

Comment: I've managed to get the code in, I can't find a later version

Answer (score 0):

this probably is the place to be

```
/**
    Create a text label that specify the dimension
*/
function specLabel( val, x, y) {

        var t = doc.textFrames.add();
        t.textRange.characterAttributes.size = 8;
        t.textRange.characterAttributes.alignment = StyleRunAlignmentType.center;

        var v = val;
        switch (doc.rulerUnits) {
            case RulerUnits.Inches: 
                v = val/dpi;
                v = v.toFixed (decimals);
                break;

            case RulerUnits.Centimeters:
                v = val/(dpi/2.54);
                v = v.toFixed (decimals);
                break;

            case RulerUnits.Millimeters:
                v = val/(dpi/25.4);
                v = v.toFixed (decimals);
                break;

            case RulerUnits.Picas:
                v = val/(dpi/6);
                var vd = v - Math.floor (v);
                vd = 12*vd;
                v =  Math.floor(v)+'p'+vd.toFixed (decimals);
                break;

            default:
                v = v.toFixed (decimals);
        }

        t.contents = v;
        t.top = y;
        t.left = x;

        return t;

}
```

to check if it would work just change the last part to

```
        t.contents = v+"mm";
        t.top = y+"mm";
        t.left = x+"mm";
        return t;
```

if so you chould check the ruler setting switch, that switches cases, your "mm" should only be there for the case RulerUnits.Millimeters

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses, I tried the code above doesn't seem to work when I press the "Specify" button if doesnt do anything, having then to force quit the application because this script doesnt have a cancel button. If I could upload a screen shot I could show you what I mean.

Comment: I'd be interested in having a cancel button too for when it crashes to save me having to force quit the application.Tried copying

    'dlg.btn = dlg.add('button', [20,70,150,90], 'Specify', 'spec');'

Didn't work thought I would have at least got 2 buttons. What can I say but I have no clue what I'm doing.